# Interest for a period

Tags: calculus

I am trying to turn my code into a maths equation if that's possible. To work out when the interest for a period is over X amount.

```
Int x = 10000;
Float Amount = 60000;
Float InterestThisPeriod =0;
Const float rate = 0.05;
Float t = 0;
Int i =0;
While(InterestThisPeriod < x){  
    t = amount * rate+1;
    InterestThisPeriod = t - Amount;
    Amount *= rate +1;   
    i++;
}

// answer is i
```

So far I have

```
p(1+r)^t - p(1+r)^(t-1) >= X
60000(1.05)^t -  60000(1.05)^(t-1) = 10000
```

But I want it in terms of x = 10000 it the formula should give me 25.something

Comment: I found the solution thanks :)

N >= ln((x+Rx) / (PR)) / ln(1+R)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure about what you are asking for. But based on your question, first, in your code, it should be:

```
t = amount * (rate+1);
```

And since you already got that far, what you need actually is:

```
60000 * (1.05 - 1) * (1.05)^ (t-1) > 10000
```

which is equal to: 
1.05 ^ (t - 1) > 20 / 6

I would expect the rest is a simple calculation.